# Code block for a LilyPond version statement alone produces a tab staff

Tags: bug

Found while answering [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/70322/32746).

The code I see:

```
\version "2.18.2"
```

[image: What I see]

What shows up:

[image]

Comment: You need you user <pre> </pre> tags if you are not using jtab or abcjs since the code blocks have those two as a parser. We do not have a lilypond parser and we will probably not get one.

Comment: Oh, interesting. I've only been using four-space indents for code blocks for LilyPond since I started. Are you saying I've just gotten lucky that they've all worked up to now?

Comment: It's possible for depending on what you are writing that jtab doesn't recognize it so it doesn't touch it, but to be safe use the pre tags.

Comment: Thanks. Shall I delete this question?

Comment: There's no reason to delete it. Others might have similar problems.